# javascript target text but not child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Ive got the following html:

```
<span class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
    Gesamt: <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0,85<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></strong>
</span>
```

My wanted output is the value `0,85` but without the currency symbol. How do I have to modify this Javascript?

```
function(){ var capturedText = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-order-overview__total span.woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText.match(/^(.*).{1}/i)[1].trim(); return capturedText; }
```

Comment: Your code works https://jsfiddle.net/4f76tjp5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) to get that text node:

```js
var capturedText = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-order-overview__total span.woocommerce-Price-amount").childNodes[0].textContent;

console.log(capturedText);
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
    Gesamt: <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0,85<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></strong>
</span>
```